# all tcp connection through socks proxy

Tags: proxy, rhel4

Is it possible to route all my connections to internet to go through a sock proxy in a RHEL 4 machine. I need to connect to a remote MySql server using socks proxy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh to build a SOCKS5 proxy for your mysql ports, or use something like squid for a complete SOCKS5 proxy solution on your RHEL4 machine.

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, the socks proxy is already available and required to get to the right servers. About 10 years since I worked with something like this, but it is possible to preload a shared library to make all tcp connections from applications go via a socks proxy. Google gives me as a first suggestion [tsocks](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tsocks) which can work this way.